# Ornamental separator of paragraphs

Tags: ornamental-fonts, separator

Sorry if this is a simple question but I need your help. What is the best way to typeset a separator (3 asterisks) among paragraphs? Please see my MWE. How can I specify to precisely center it vertically between the two paragraphs? Thanks

```
\documentclass{octavo}
\usepackage[
twoside=true,
paperwidth=115mm, paperheight=195mm,
textheight=15.5cm,
textwidth=8.5cm,
left=1.3cm,
right=1.7cm,
top=1.7cm,
bottom=2.2cm
]
    {geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\vspace{3pt}
\begin{center}
***
\end{center}
\vspace{3pt}

A one line paragraph.

\vspace{3pt}
\begin{center}
***
\end{center}
\vspace{3pt}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the current output exactly? Precise vertical spacing may be tricky unless you remove the stretchiness of TeX's spacing, but you really don't want to do that. Why do you want precisely equal vertical spaces here?

Comment: If you choose an ornament centred on the baseline, the vertical spaces should look equal. `*` is typeset quite high above the baseline, so your ornament is effectively bringing extra space with it, I think.

Comment: @cfr Yes you are right it might be a bad idea to have fixed spacing. The thing is sometimes in the course of a 200 pages book there are many cases in which the latex stretching is unpleasant to the eye and I have to correct by adding space manually modifying the \vspace.

Comment: @cfr Maybe I should just make things easier with an ornament on the baseline. How would I force an asterisk on the baseline? Thanks!

Comment: `$***$`?! 12345

Comment: I guess you'd want it centred on the vertical centre of an `x` rather than the baseline, which should be "about right" assuming ascenders and descenders are more-or-less equal.

Comment: Yes. This works much better  in terms of spacing, although it produces a slightly different asterisk. But the bottom line is: I will let latex stretch the space as needed and continue correcting manually as needed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you use stretchy manual adjustments, I find I need fewer of them. E.g. `\bigskip`, `\smallskip` etc. tend to work better than `3pt` or something in the end.

Comment: Yes I use those generally but sometimes I needed to fine-tune with \vspace. Thanks

Comment: @Haim Two tips: 1) in order to center the asterisk without using math mode (i.e. `$***$`), you could use a `\raisebox`, e.g. `\raisebox{-2pt}{***}`. You have to find the right amount of correction. 2) `memoir` class has a `\fancybreak` command for such decorations, you may have a look at its definition.

Comment: You can use the optional arguments of `\raisebox` to add space above and below; e.g `\raisebox{-2pt][1em][1em]{***}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo  Thanks this helps!

Comment: @lacobus1983 Thanks! I do not use memoir but octavo, but I will take a look thanks for pointing me to it